# custom error message in my PHP function

Tags: php

I still trying to get around in PHP as a language am kind of confused over  this operation, I have a custom error message `array()` and I want to put whatsoever my function echos into the custom error `array()` message I have.

Please help, thanks in advance...

```
 $msg = array();

    $spam = "hate partisan party kill maim murder violence love sex fight beat assasinate thug steal sell bribe protest baricade bullets militia fear ";
$spam_array = explode(" ",$spam);
$isSpam = isSpam($_POST['msgTextArea'], $spam_array);


function isSpam($content, $spamList)
{
    foreach($spamList as $badWord) {
        if(stripos($content, $badWord) !== false) {
         $msg['new'] =  return "Spam filter rejects your message! try again.";
        }
```

Is it possible to return this like this:

```
 $msg['new'] =  return "Spam filter rejects your message! try again.";
```

Comment: Ok so you want to store the error message in the array based on a value put into the function? So you want it `$msg['new']` to equal `Hello world!`?

Comment: Just do `return "Hello world!";` instead of `echo "Hello world!";` in your function

Comment: Ok I you want to store the error message in the array based on a value put into the function? I want it $msg['new'] = "Hello World"; returned instead of Hello world!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand you, but if I do you just need to replace "echo" by "return"...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on what you supplied:

```
function isSpam($content = false, $spamList = "hate,partisan,party,kill,maim,murder,violence,love,sex,fight,beat,assasinate,thug,steal,sell,bribe,protest,baricade,bullets,militia,fear")
    {
        // You can feed the string or an array
        $spam_array =   (!is_array($spamList))? explode(",",$spamList) : $spamList;
        // Loop through the list and match
        foreach($spam_array as $badWord) {
                if(stripos($content, $badWord) !== false)
                    return "Spam filter rejects your message! try again.";
            }
    }

$msg['new'] = isSpam($_POST['msgTextArea']);
```

Comment: I want whatsoever yo have returned into my $msg[] array

Comment: Give me an example of what you would like to see returned into your `$msg['new']` based on `$Result1 = "90";`

Comment: function isSpam($content, $spamList)
{
    foreach($spamList as $badWord) {
        if(stripos($content, $badWord) !== false) {
   return "Spam filter rejects your message! try again.";
   $msg['new'] =  isSpam($content, $spamList);
        }

Comment: I want the  return "Spam filter rejects your message! try again."; output by my $msg['new'] = isSpam($content, $spamList);